# C# .NET SQL Server 2008 Data vanished after insert or unchanged after edit

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 in a C# environment.

I can insert or update data into the server without any error, but the database become unchanged after some time. I closed the connection after edit, used transaction and commit, but there was no luck.

Can anyone help me please??

Comment: Can you edit your answer and show some codes where your'e having a problem?

Comment: It looks like a rollback, it quacks like a rollback... show us the code.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: or it might be the `AttachDbFileName=/User Instance` stuff again where VS copies around `.mdf` files at runtime.....

Comment: thanks @marc_s
it was the problem with instance...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you may make sure that you have properly used transaction management: commit/rollback. Otherwise, if both insert or update data are not affecting the database sometimes, check whether you are using disconnected ado.net data objects such as dataAdapter,dataset, datatable and etc to update your data. They might be cauisng this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...

Do I really need to use these transactions and commit??

Comment: To my mind, transaction management is a must to a system. For example, you have to insert data into one table and update another table. If an error is raised after insert, update part will not be executed. Consequently, you database will not be consistent. This is just a very obvious and simple example of a system without proper transaction management. With transaction management, if there is an error, transaction will be rolled back and your database will be as before.